# Who is the controller of an Aura when the creature it enchants is stolen?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Cockatrice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCockatrice%5d) enchanted with an aura, [Celestial Mantle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCelestial%20Mantle%5d), which says:

> Whenever enchanted creature deals combat damage to a player, double its controller’s life total.

My opponent then enchants the Cockatrice with [Control Magic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bControl%20Magic%5d). Next turn, they attack with it.

Who's the controller of the Celestial Mantle at this stage? Who will benefit from Celestial Mantle's ability to double a player's life total?

- The player who put the Aura onto the creature, or
- The player controlling the creature?

Comment: (I'm pretty sure the answer is - the current Cockatrice controller - but I thought I'd ask you the same ...)

Comment: duplicate of: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45857/who-controls-negative-creature-enchantments

Comment: Well, I disagree: my question is an evidence of the opposite situation...and that this kind of situations happens, and that is a proper and different question.

Comment: Not really, it is 'who controls a permanent' which is something that has been answered several times here ;)

Comment: Ok, but how coould I know this?

Comment: FWIW I think that your questions have had value in revisiting other questions from a different perspective. Querying this site for other questions is the first step, it is expected that a question has some research behind it before it is asked. However this is a complex game and duplicates happen. At that point it should be the responsibility of the community and its moderators to consolidate the questions which increases the value of any given question on the site. This whole stack should be a living document of crowd-sourced truths for the rest of the world to use to solve their problems :)

Comment: I agree with this. Thus, wait a little for my next question...

Comment: Although it has been unfairly closed, my question about "Singing Bell Strike" (please see it)  shows another example of the fact that kind of Aura's situations often have to be seen one by one. This, of course, is especially true for beginners. Certainly not for an expert like you, Ayatollah ...

Comment: However, even if it actually resembles the questions it was associated with, this situation can cause some problems because it is the creature's controller that doubles its life points, and not the Aura's controller. It is possible to be easily mistaken, and so the question is not exactly the same as Ajatollah of Rock'n Rolla refers to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're still controlling the aura.

> 303.4e An Aura’s controller is separate from the enchanted object’s controller or the enchanted player; the two need not be the same. If an Aura enchants an object, changing control of the object doesn’t change control of the Aura, and vice versa. Only the Aura’s controller can activate its abilities. However, if the Aura grants an ability to the enchanted object (with “gains” or “has”), the enchanted object’s controller is the only one who can activate that ability.

However, in this case it doesn't matter. The aura says

> double its controller's life total

"its" refers to the enchanted creature, not the aura itself. So your opponent will get the benefits here.

Comment: In fact, it's like I thought ... I also said it in the comment above. I ask for it just to make sure about. it is a quite simple question...                                                       
But please...don't rate me bad for doing this!!!

Comment: It can however be useful for beginners, or for a quick recognition of the rules about this kind of topics...

Comment: Anyway...Gendolkari you are right....card text says: "its controller's life total", and it is not "it's" like Glorfinder wrote it, because is a possessive pronoun.... (english is not my mother language....! did you understand that already?)

Comment: @Massimiliano An aura and its target are less connected than one might intuitively think. I know many people, for instance, tap auras on creatures that attack. That might often be just a convenience, but it's easy to believe that the auras _actually_ tap if you haven't been specifically told that they don't. In fact, placing it under or on top of the card it enchants is also "a convenience". Pedantically (at least according to the Comp rules; I know little of tournament rules), one might just as well play them out on the table completely separate like any other card. But please don't.

Comment: An interesting thing is that older Auras and Equipment tended to give benefits to their controllers such as Spirit Link, and newer enchantments tend to give the benefits to the Enchanted/Equiped permanent.

Comment: Also note cards like [Vow of Flight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=451065) (there's a full five color rotation of similar auras), which would be completely pointless if ownership of an aura was synced with the permanent it's enchanting.

Comment: @Arthur And the whole putting cards on the side of the table that corresponds with their controller is also a matter of pure convenience.

Comment: Well,I'm quite sure that is as you answer to me.I started having doubt about it when reading the Gatherer's Rulings about this card.It says:-"At the time the ability triggers,determine which creature CM is enchanting.As the ability resolves,determine who currently controls that creature(or, if it’s no longer on the battlefield, determine who controlled it when it left).That’s the player whose life total is doubled.It doesn’t matter who controls CM,who controlled the creature at the time the ability triggered, or what creature C M enchants at the time the ability resolves". What do you think?

Comment: Anyway, the reason why I asked about such an apparently simple question is precisely this: it is not always said that an Aura,and what it enchants, are linked, in the sense that controller of the one may not necessarily be the controller of the other.

Comment: @Massimiliano indeed, there's nothing stopping you from enchanting the opponent's creatures, even without Control Magic and other controller change shenanigans. As for the Gatherer ruling, it addresses a rather narrow case where you steal the enchanted creature while Celestial Mantle's trigger is still on the stack. In short - which creature counts for CM's ability is checked when it triggers, but who gets the life is checked when it resolves. Moving CM to one of your creatures in response to the trigger won't let you get double life points, but stealing the creature it's enchanting will.

Comment: I, and You too, must admit that it is a brainy situation ... anyway, a good way to get away with one of these situations - assuming it was "you" who suffered the theft of the creature - is to use the really underrated "Dispotic Scepter" card, which in one case like this looks really useful ...